# Computing $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6}):\mathbb{Q}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

If $p$ is a prime, the polynomial $X^n-p$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, so $\sqrt[n]{p}
 $ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$. Hence $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{p}):\mathbb{Q}]$.

But $p$ is not a prime, how do we compute $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{p}):\mathbb{Q}]$? For example, compute $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6}):\mathbb{Q}]$

Help me.

Thank for any insight.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Maths.SE. Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Comment: Oh, of course. Thank you for editting it.

Comment: Your first paragraph ends in mid-sentence.

Comment: The degree of ${\bf Q}(\alpha)$ is the degree of the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$.

Comment: In your example $X^2 - 6$ is still irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, so there's hardly a difference with the prime number case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that $\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}[\Q(\sqrt 6):\Q]\leq 2$ since $\sqrt 6$ is a root of $X^2-6$.

But actually $6$ is square-free meaning it is not divisible twice by any prime $p$. Hence Eisenstein's Criterion shows that $X^2-6$ is irreducible over $\Q$. Simply choose $p=2$ or $p=3$ to argue this.

It follows that $[\Q(\sqrt 6):\Q]=2$.

Comment: Broadly, how do we compute $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5},\sqrt{11}):\mathbb{Q}]$? Does it equal to $2^3$?

Comment: Yes: having degree $2$, $\sqrt 3$ provides us with the basis $1,\sqrt 3$ for the extension $\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}\Q(\sqrt 3)$ over $\Q$. Since $\sqrt 5$ is in-expressible in this basis (think about that first), $\sqrt 5$ must have degree $2$ over $\Q(\sqrt 3)$, so by the degree formula $\Q(\sqrt 3,\sqrt 5)$ has degree $4$ over $\Q$, the basis being $1,\sqrt 3,\sqrt 5,\sqrt 3\sqrt 5$. Similarly it is seen that $\sqrt 11$ extends $\Q(\sqrt 3,\sqrt 5)$ by degree $2$ again leading to $[\Q(\sqrt 3,\sqrt 5):\Q]=8$ by the degree formula once again.

Comment: Thank you for your support.